# regex - is this matching task impossible?

Tags: regex

Here is a filename of a TV show.
Let's say I want to extract the title and year from this text

B6549887_MAC_THE_PERPETUALLY_ANGRY_CAT_YR06_12_07_2010_2J7211_00_23_14_09_8884889_3_16x9_6545665

I would match the first and onlystring of alpha characters (capital only) and dashes, which happen to terminate with digits.

I would want to include the digits but not the succeeding underscore.

That would give me MAC_THE_PERPETUALLY_ANGRY_CAT_YR06

Would this involve lookahead? (which I haven't studied yet)?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/([A-Z][A-Z_]+)_YR(\d{2})/
```

The above would match "MAC_THE_PERPETUALLY_ANGRY_CAT_YR06" and give you "MAC_THE_PERPETUALLY_ANGRY_CAT" in your first backreference and "06" in your second backreference.

Comment: thanks sir! you made it look easy. With that helpful nudge, I got ([A-Z][A-Z_]+\d{1,2})

Comment: My pleasure: Here's a useful link for testing regexes that I sometimes use: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/